# How to manage group of threads to modify the instance variable after the callback is received?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, callback

I have sensitive question which I didn't know how to explain, but tried to draw. If you don't understand I would try to uncover more the problem.
So I have 3 different groups of thread.

- Main thread (M)
- Threads created by MAIN to receive callbacks later (T)
- Always running Sync thread created by MAIN earlier, which sends callbacks to MAIN asynchronously. (S)

In the class where M is located there is token variable defined, which is given to the T group of sub threads to give back with callback to identify where the callback comes from.

But as I have async thread working parallel, which sends callbacks to the main thread, it changes this token on a async way, by which I lose the information which I gave to the T group. So I can't identify where the callback comes from anymore. My question how is it better to write or pass this token part to the threads to identify them in the main thread later.

The purpose of the token is to identify the callbacks, to be able to process accordingly, because each single thread executes a query on the database and I need to know which result do I have in callback. I mean which query was executed.

To make it more clear I have drawn a picture, do not know how else to explain this issue...

[image]

I have this issue in Android application, but it is more about the concept, but not the platform.

Comment: What is the point of given a "token" to somebody (so he can return it to me); when it is already clear that I might not accept that very "token" later on? What I mean is: you already described that the whole thing doesn't make sense; so what do you expect us to tell you beyond that? Meaning: either you need that token to stay the same; then you can't change it. Or you allow it to be changed; but then you have to deal with that (for example by "remembering" previous tokens).

Comment: Why do you share the token with the thread group and async task?

Comment: The purpose of the token is to identify the callbacks, to be able to process accordingly, because each single thread executes a query on the database and I need to know which result do I have in callback. I mean which query was executed.

Comment: How does your callback method look like? You can pass the thread name.

Comment: Dont put additional information into comments - update your question instead. And I think you just gave yourself an answer: if your "token" has such an important value ... then you simply have to make sure you "manage" its "life time". If it matters when your tokens get into existence, and when new ones are added, and old ones get discarded ... well, then you have to write code to manage all of that.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)s ... And it is pretty clear to me, that you do not need **a** token, but a whole set of tokens. One for each request startet.